# Can't access Arrays class in IntelliJ randomly

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having some problems being able to use the Arrays class and streams in the intelliJ 14.1 IDE. I was able to use them before, but I can't now. Even in new projects.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

My project is using JDK 1.8.0_25 with project language level 8.

Does anyone have a solution? I've restarted the IDE, remade the project, restarted the computer, I don't have a clue what to do.

Comment: could you show some code? it should work, altough.

Comment: @NagyVilmos There's not really any code to show, I simply don't have any access to the Arrays class. I can't import it or anything.

Comment: @Chritstian.tucker yeah, i understand. No misspelling, bad import, something like this?

Comment: @NagyVilmos - Not at all, my previous projects won't compile anymore as-well.

Comment: I would try to write a simple class, and compile it from command line/terminal, to see, `javac` works well. If that compiles, than the error is in IDEA, otherwise the error is in the JDK.